# ExtJS 6 - add resizable image / logo to a topmenu

Tags: css, image, extjs6

I'm redesigning a frontend for a uni project written with ExtJS 6.
right now I'm wondering how to properly add an image to a container that fits the size:

I tried a displayfield using value: "img=.../>" but I can't seem to make the image fit properly - it's just way to big. The same goes for "html: img=.../>".

also adressing id: 'TopMenu'  with #TopMenu{} in css seems to have no effect whatsoever regardless of the options I try to change :(
I suspect ExtJS defaults have higher priority than my own settings or I'm simply not adressing the container right.

```
    Ext.define('textImager.view.menu.TopMenu', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    // id für css: #TopMenu
    id: 'TopMenu',
    xtype: 'TopMenu',
    layout: 'hbox',
    items: [
    // goethe logo
    {
        flex: 1,
        id: 'GoetheLogo'
    },
    // Website titel
    {
        flex: 8,
        id: 'Titel', 
        html: 'TextImager'
    },
    // dropdown menu
    {
        flex: 1,
        id: 'DropdownMenu', 
        xtype: 'button',
        html: 'menu',
        menu: [
        {xtype: 'button',
        html: 'test1'}]
    },

    ]
});
```

the current css:

```
 #TopMenu-body{}
 #GoetheLogo-body{
    background-image:url(../resources/images/menu/TT_logo_transparent.png);
    background-position: right center;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background: rgba(123,123, 123, 0.8);
 }
 #Titel{}
 #DropdownMenu{}
```

simply resizing would be a bad workaround and I also have to adjust the background which currently is not working either.

I would greatly appreciate some insight on how to properly adress the containers with css.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution - it might not be the best, but I'm quite happy with the result:

```
// TT logo mit Link zur Website
    {
        flex: 1,
        xtype: 'button',
        height: '100%',
        //TODO: add link
        html: '<div class="TT_logo"><img src="./resources/images/menu/TT_logo_transparent.png"></div>'
    },
```

css:

```
.TT_logo{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
.TT_logo img{
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```